# Passing chrome.identity to firebase login

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-chrome-app

I would like to know if you think it's possible to pass on or link a authenticated user with `[chrome.identity][1]` to Firebase.

Why? Because for Google Cloud Print connected with a classic printer a user has to be signed in at Chrome and Chrome needs to be openend to keep the printer online. For UX it would be cool if I can open a webbpage with Firebase login inside a chrome webapp **AND** could verify the user with chrome.identity. But I don't want to ask them twice to log in, or create two separate apps.

So the basic question is: If I have verified a user with chrome.identity, can I create an account for them in Firebase as well, and can I pass on webtokens between each other?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about chrome.identity but it appears that it provides a method to get the Google OAuth access token:
https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity#method-getAuthToken

You can sign in with chrome.identity, get the OAuth2.0 google access token and then sign in to Firebase:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(null,googleOAuth2AccessToken))
```

This would prevent the need to prompt the user to sign in more than once.